# Changing font in console application to Raster Font

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to change the font of my console application to the Raster Font. Here is an image of the font and where you can set it:

[image: CMD Screenshot]

My question is how can I do this in my C++ application? Is there a certain name for it? This is what I have so far:

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cf;
cf.cbSize = sizeof cf;
cf.dwFontSize.X = 6;
cf.dwFontSize.Y = 8;
wcscpy_s(cf.FaceName, L"NEED NAME HERE");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0, &cf);
```

"Raster", "Raster Font", "Raster Fonts", "RasterFont", "RasterFonts", "Font Raster", "Fonts Raster", "FontRaster", "FontsRaster", and "Font" all haven't worked for me. Is there a different way to set it or some different name it goes by?

Comment: You can use this name: Terminal for raster font

Comment: You're amazing! Post this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer, @Asesh

Comment: I have done it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set font face name to terminal for raster font:

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cf = {0};
cf.cbSize = sizeof cf;
cf.dwFontSize.X = 6;
cf.dwFontSize.Y = 8;
wcscpy_s(cf.FaceName, L"Terminal");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 0, &cf);
```

Comment: You are not initializing all members of `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`.

Comment: @zett42 Now I have, thanks